# How can I use FFMPEG to convert video to black and white, but leave one color / color range?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have been researching and cannot find anything on how to preserve just one color / color range while converting a video to greyscale / black & white using FFMPEG. For example; all black and white, except the people's Blue Jeans, etc.

Anyone know how to do this in FFMPEG?